# Tray icons created by java apps keep disappearing

Tags: unity, java, icons, system-tray

I have two java apps with tray icons that keep disappearing. As I have lots of use for the said tray icons this actually matters for me.

The apps are written by myself and there is nothing funky going on with the icons and they worked just fine earlier (on 15.10 I think, now running 16.04).

The icons sometime work just fine for long, but sometimes disappear even after a fresh reboot.

When I switch between workspaces the icons become visible during the transition animation but disappear immediately after the animation is done.

I've got a run-of-the-mill unity running with no noteworthy hacks running.

24 workspaces, apps running are a few chromium & firefox windows (one of the ff ones is always full screen but does not seem to affect this), IntelliJ, Atom and some terminal windows.

Comment: Seems like the icons become visible iff. the workspace switcher is on if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using the `menulibre` app and use it to create a custom launcher with a command similar to `java -jar /path/to/folder/yourjar.jar`

It's in the repos, so you can just use `sudo apt-get install menulibre`

HTH